# MongoDB search case insensitive for Field not Value

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I am using `MongoDB` with `C#` using `MongoDB.Driver`. Now I want to search data from mongodb collection with case insensitive(**For both - Key and Value**). For this I have tried below code in C#.

```
var filter = new List<BsonElement>
{
    new BsonElement("IsDeleted", false) // it could be "isdeleted" in database
};

var obj = await collection.FindAsync(new BsonDocument(filterList));
```

Now, as you can see above code, I want to apply search and fetch data where `IsDeleted/isdeleted` flag is `false`. But the issue is, In database for some records the `Key` is `IsDeleted` and for some it is `isdeleted` so the above code is only working where `IsDeleted=false` But not working where `isdeleted=false`. So I need a way to make the searching case-insensitive for **`Key`**.

Comment: You need to fix your code. This cannot be done.

Comment: @NeilLunn Could you please explain me where I went wrong So I can modified accordingly.

Comment: Property names **ARE** case sensitive. It's part of the BSON specification so there is no way to change that. If you wrote documents with varying case on those properties, then there is no coding to "work around that" and instead you go back and fix the documents where you incorrectly wrote the properties in the incorrect case. You can use `Or` conditions everywhere, but that's not practical. Just fix the problem instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn But like in SQL we know that the column name are case insensitive while we execute the query. So Is there any way in MongoDB ?

Comment: This is not SQL. Nor is that a true generalization as I can clearly think of several SQL RDBMS which consider field names case sensitive as well. Only "some" don't. I've been pretty clear and there is nothing more to say on the subject.